# Wrap code to a usable method in Android

Tags: java, android

am trying to create a clickable text amidst so block of text, i was lucky to find out the code on stackoverflow that works for me, but the issue is that have many other text where i want to apply the clicking. my question now is that if it's possible to bundle the below code in a reuse-able method that i can call and pass the needed parameters and how

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 10, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 10, 27, 0);

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Below is what i have resolve to use, any suggestion on how to make it better?

```
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.one) ;
    String s="This link has many clickable text which are link one, link two 
    and the last whick is link three";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
    String one ="link one";
    String two ="link two";
    String three ="link three";
    int firstIndex = s.indexOf(one);
    int secondIndex = s.indexOf(two);
    int thirdIndex = s.indexOf(three);

    ClickableSpan firstClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, a.class));
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan secondClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, b.class));
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ClickableSpan thirdClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, c.class));
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(firstClick,firstIndex, firstIndex+one.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(secondClick,secondIndex, secondIndex+two.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(thirdClick,thirdIndex, thirdIndex+three.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setLinksClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(ss, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: What would you like to alter with new method? Existing text widget where you know R.id? How do you know which parts of text shall be affected?

Comment: You need to list your parametric need to be able to create a subclass of `SpannableString` that would match your need.

Comment: leos-literak, i want to be able to call the method on few chunk of text at interval, just like answer given by Droidman

Comment: leos-literak, i want to be able to set multiple ClickableSpan text in a textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you always need to start some `Activity` when the user clicks a part of text, it could look like that:

```
@UiThread
public static void setClickable(@NonNull TextView tv, 
                                @NonNull SpannableString ss, 
                                int start, int end, 
                                @NonNull final Context from, @NonNull final Class to){

    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            from.startActivity(new Intent(from, to));
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), start, end, 0);
    tv.setText(ss);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    tv.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Usage example (based on your given use-case, called from an `Activity`):

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    setClickable(textView, ss, 10, 27, this, NextActivity.class);
```

Notes: `Context.startActivity()` is available starting with API 16, below that API you'd need to use an `Activity` instance instead of `Context`. Also feel free to add/remove the parameters accodring to your needs. The example above will work from any class and aims to give you some basic idea how to implement what you need.

Comment: am getting this error

Variable 'from' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final and Variable 'to' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: @shollynoob y, I missed that since I didn't test that code. Just declare those parameters final

Comment: i tried i didn't get it right, i will appreciate if you can modify the code

Comment: @shollynoob check the last edit. Also what IDE are you using? AS by default assumes those params are final in such a case and doesn't give an error

Comment: droidman You are the Man thanks, it works

Am using Android Studio